# Where could I find documentation of python/dyn or python3/dyn?

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I guess that `:py` command is executed by some kind of extended Python interpreter. This extended Python has `vim` package available:

```
:py import vim; print(dir(vim)); print(vim.__package__, vim.__name__)
```

outputs:

```
['Buffer', 'Dictionary', 'Function', 'List', 'Options', 'Range', 'TabPage', 
'VAR_DEF_SCOPE', 'VAR_FIXED', 'VAR_LOCKED', 'VAR_SCOPE', 'VIM_SPECIAL_PATH', 'Window',
'_Loader', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', '_chdir', '_fchdir', '_find_module',
'_get_paths', '_getcwd', '_load_module', 'bindeval', 'buffers', 'chdir', 'command',
'current', 'error', 'eval', 'fchdir', 'find_module', 'foreach_rtp', 'options', 'os',
'path_hook', 'strwidth', 'tabpages', 'vars', 'vvars', 'windows']
(None, 'vim')
```

Where could I find the documentation of this `vim` package?

Comment: I have found some kind of documentation https://vimhelp.org/if_pyth.txt.html. Is there a more detailed documentation or even source code?

Comment: The help file is the documentation. Or have a look at the source code in the vim repository.